# Parsing csv records depending upon field values seperation

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I am reading csv file records using csvhelper, but I have noticed that sometimes csv fields values are separated by blankspace(\t) and sometimes
field values are separated by comma.

Now I have 6 columns, but as field values are separated by blankspace I am getting all records in single column. So while fetching a column value for the second field I get the error : **Field at index '1' does not exist.**

So I am getting the error when reading records:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(sr);
reader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
reader.Configuration.IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace = true;
reader.ReadHeader();
var headers = reader.Parser.RawRecord.Split(new[] { ',', '\t' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()).
Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray(); //6 columns


foreach (var header in headers) {
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
    col.ColumnName = header;
    dt.Columns.Add(col);
}
reader.Read();

do {
    DataRow drRow = dt.NewRow();
    for (int iThColumn = 0; iThColumn < headers.Count(); iThColumn++) {
        var data =  reader.GetField<string>(iThColumn);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            drRow[iThColumn] = null;
        else
            drRow[iThColumn] = reader.GetField<string>(iThColumn);

    }
    dt.Rows.Add(drRow);

} while (reader.Read());
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with debugging it, and before trying to split via a comma, replace all tab instances with commas first?

Comment: Being pedantic, a CSV (comma-separated values) file cannot have tabs as a delimiter.

Comment: Do you mean that you have mixed separators in the *same* file? Then you probably have a broken CSV file. Otherwise, you can provide the column, row separators you want to CsvReader

Comment: @Phylogenesis on the same vein, CSV isn't any kind of standard, just a loosely defined format. Most European countries for example use `;` as a separator, because `,` is the decimal separator

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos See [this RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). There *is* a standard.

Comment: Anyway if it is a CSV it should be separated with the same criteria

Comment: @Learning why are you using CsvReader then splitting manually? You can set the field separator to a tab with `reader.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";`

Comment: @Phylogenesis I know about the RFC. The problem is that CSV files were used many decades before that RFC came out,  as a *quick and dirty* way of importing/exporting data. Did you notice the RFC requires that there is no ending line separator? That RFC can be interpreted as "If you use `text/csv` your file must follow this format".

Comment: It's the opposite way round. It *requires* a terminating CRLF. It should be noted, however, that many RFCs were created after they were actually in use as an attempt to document and standardise the usage at the time. As such, there's no real excuse (and hinders interoperability) to write software nowadays that does not follow the standard given. For example this question would not have been asked as there would not need to be any configurable parameters.

Comment: @Phylogenesis and that one is [still a work in progress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#History) while CSV where introduced in 1972. So, there is no concrete standard, certainly not for the typical *non* HTTP related data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:No i dont have a mixed seperators in my file.I have a list of files which i am trying to read and what happens is that some csv files have field values seperated by comma and some have field values seperated by blank space(\t).So i am not getting how to handle this scenario

Comment: @Learning why don't you just change the separator before reading? Why all this code that tries to manually parse the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CsvHelper : How to detect the Delimiter from the given csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341307/csvhelper-how-to-detect-the-delimiter-from-the-given-csv-file)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos :Sir i have already seen that answer but as you can see that author is saying that it is not possible

Comment: @Learning that's *not* what the duplicate question says. You can try to detect the separator from the header, or just try with different headers until one returns meaningful data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:Are you saying that i should use tha answer given by Maraboc ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131814/discussion-between-learning-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: You can read the first line and check how many tabs there are, eg even with a quick & dirty `String.Split`. If the count and values make sense, you have tabs. Or just ask whoever creates these files to use different extenstions, eg `tsv`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : can you provide some code so i can create something by taking reference of it please